# SSIS - Copying file only when no locks on it

Tags: ssis, file-copying

I have an SSIS job which copies the input files from FTP server to local server and does lot of processing. These input files are pretty large in size and when the external Vendor pushes them to our FTP server it takes about 5 mins to receive the full contents of the file.

When my package copies the files; I want to make sure that I don't copy partial files; i.e I don't want to copy the files when they are still being pushed to FTP server. I guess I can achieve this by checking for file lock before copying the file and if there is any lock wait for 10 mins and try again. Can anyone please let me know how can i check for file locks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

In the solution below I was checking for local file locks.  The solution in the stated case is to ask the vendor to post a small flag file on the FTP Server after the full file is loaded and ready for download.  Check for the existence of the flag file before starting download of the full file.

**End Edit**

I used the following in a script task to check for file locks:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        string strTracePath = Dts.Variables["uv_TraceFilePath"].Value.ToString();
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(strTracePath);
        try
        {
            Dts.Variables["uv_TraceFileSize"].Value = fInfo.Length;
            fInfo.MoveTo(strTracePath + "_old");
            FileInfo fInfoOld = new FileInfo(strTracePath + "_old");
            fInfoOld.MoveTo(strTracePath);

            Dts.Variables["uv_ProcessTraceFile"].Value = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            Dts.Variables["uv_ProcessTraceFile"].Value = false;
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

The task attempts to move the file (to the same folder) while renaming it.  If this suceeds then it moves it back to the original name.  On success it sets a variable to true.  On failure it sets the variable to false. Coming out of this task I use conditional precedence constraints to decide what to do next.  To make this work, I added a `Using System.IO;` declaration at the top of the script.

Comment: I don't think this approach will work for the OP scenario. They are attempting to check for locks over FTP, not the local file system. Perhaps issuing a double rename from FTP would accomplish the same results...

Comment: Re-Reading the question it appears that the OP is copying locally from \\Local_FTP_Server\ShareName to \\Local_SSIS_Server\ShareName. So if he attempts the local rename while the external FTP process is still writing, it should throw the error in the script which the Catch block will catch.  So I believe my original script would work, however, a flag file sent from the vendor to the local FTP after the Full File has completed the FTP process is also a clean (and less risky) way to manage this.